# Which AMI for remote graphics processing on Windows?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm new to EC2.  I went through the process of creating an instance. I used a p3-2xl because the hardware fit my needs.  However, I didn't know much about AMIs, so I just picked Windows Server 2016 in the "quick start" section.  I had all kinds of trouble with the server.  Obviously RDP did not work because the [software I'm using](https://www.capturingreality.com/) could not see the graphics card.  After multiple failed attempts to get VNC communicating (TightVNC, UltraVNC...) I finally [found this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/accelerated-computing-instances.html#gpu-instance-specifications):

> When using Microsoft Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP), GPUs that use the WDDM driver model are replaced with a non-accelerated Remote Desktop display driver. To access your GPU hardware, you must use a different remote access tool, such as Teradici Cloud Access Software, NICE Desktop Cloud Visualization (DCV), or VNC. **You can also use one of the GPU AMIs from the AWS Marketplace because they provide remote access tools that support 3D acceleration**.

The only AMI I found when searching for GPU and Windows was "[Microsoft Windows Server 2016 with NVIDIA Tesla Driver](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07C5F5QKR?qid=1530201406591&sr=0-1&ref_=srh_res_product_title)".  But upon reading the description, I don't see any mention of any remote tools preinstalled.  It looks like it's just the driver, which I already installed manually.  I don't want to spend the time and money launching that one only to discover I'm in the exact same place.

So I guess my question is, is there a Windows AMI somewhere that has remote access already set up for 3D/graphics processing software?

Any input or tips would be *greatly* appreciated.

Comment: You could consider TeamViewer on the standard AMI.

Comment: I finally got VNC working. I had to add a row to the default security profile in EC2.  When I get back to the office on Monday I'll write up a proper answer.

Comment: hey did you get anywhere with this?